# Same database structure and Model, different databases

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

This problem should not be unique, but I haven't found anything sufficiently similar.

I have to write a C# application to maintain two existing databases, so I made a database-first solution. The databases (and generated models) are structurally identical, but must be separated in two.
I would, of course, like my code to be non-duplicated, and which database to actually operate on should be made a parameter. But I end up with two generated contexts, and I cannot cast one to the other.

How to do it?

Comment: If databases and models are **unique** (which means not equal), how would you like to **not to have** two contexts?

Comment: Fair question, and my mistake! "Identical" was the actual word.

Comment: if they are identical why have two contexts?  just switch the connection string

Comment: may be you forgot to update the connection string in app.config of edmx?

Comment: This is definitely due to inexperience. Switching connstrings certainly seems to be the way to go, but how? I tried:
`db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[<one_of_the _strings>].ConnectionString;`
but those are not the same type of string. The Connection.ConnectionString seems to be what is part of the web.config, called "provider connection string".